# What is left in physics for a scientist in the Star Wars galaxy to study?

Tags: science-in-society, scientific-development

I know this question may be considered too broad, but I legitimately wonder what physics science; scientists are working on in Star Wars. Many many people have said that there is no scientific progression in Star Wars; but I don’t believe that. Scientist characters are featured in stories and surely they must be doing something! That something is never revealed but I can’t help but speculate. I think they probably know what dark matter and dark energy are since Starkiller Base is powered by it. They probably know what the full size of the universe is, how it started, how it will end and why their is more matter than anti-matter.

They obviously know the origin of consciousness and how to create it since they have “sentient” droids.

That being said, what is left to wonder about, specifically in physics.

Comment: You may have some luck asking this question on the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) Stack but here it's [Off Topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a number of reasons.

Comment: I already tried that one. They put it on hold. I really want to write a Star Wars fan fic. Please let others try and answer it.

Comment: The problem is that the answer is basically "_whatever is needed for the next production's handwavium_", which is only known to the authors (eg. yourself). Alternatively, it devolves to an open-ended list of theoretical technologies that they don't have yet, and that's gonna end up being a bit broad and opinionated.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. On the entire Stack Exchange questions have to fit the scope of the community where they are posted, because they belong to the community. This question is not about worldbuilding, and even it was, it doesn't fit our standards. We request questions to be answerable, and you are just asking for a list of missing items. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to find out more

Comment: Even the main films of the Star Wars franchise span nearly a century, and the wider universe has millennia of fictional history, so an important question to think about is _when_ your story is set. You list the technology needed for the Starkiller Base as "already known", but at some point those had to be discovered, so quite likely that was a subject of research in the decades leading up to that point. It's also entirely plausible that there's more to be discovered in the same area, and new applications of the technology to be developed.

Comment: Okay. I guess I’m thinking the science wondering is by the time of the canon New Republic.

Comment: Quite obviously, since space travel by means of magic mushrooms has already been discovered and put into practice in another (formerly less childish) franchise, the next object of study would be [seven league boots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-league_boots). Or maybe [face dancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_Dancer). Or maybe prescience, or maybe genetic memory, or maybe mentat training. *Science never ends:* the only limitation is the imagination of Disney's scriptwriters.

Comment: I *swear* this exact question was asked here before by another user.

Comment: Apparently they haven't figure out how to make decent body armor for storm troopers, or for that matter an accurate gun.  They could start there.

Comment: They would start figuring out how to get to the Galaxy next door? Or maybe figure out how to get to ludicrous speed.

Comment: How to explain to people that doing Kessel run in parsecs means the shortest distance and not time?

Comment: Just because you know what something is and how it behaves does not mean that you have the most optimal way to utilize it in any given application nor does every possible application become evident. Scientists probably "play around" with mixing different combinations together to find new effects and previously unknown applications. There is also the search for undiscovered properties of known materials and new, undiscovered materials. Not very different from us actually...

Comment: [I knew this had been asked before](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/146469/32016), or at least something very similar. (10k users only) And both by users named Max...

Answer (score 9):

Answer from a Worldbuilding Perspective:

Sorry, but you're kind of barking up the wrong tree. Star Wars is a 'Space Opera' and is built from a soft sci-fi basis. Every part of the Star Wars universe is crafted from a perspective of 'How can we take fantasy concepts and make them IN SPACE' and flagrantly ripping things off from what already existed (*cough* DUNE *cough*), not hard sci-fi. Coruscant, for instance, was actually created by (I believe) Timothy Zahn in a novel and incorporated into the prequel trilogy. Technology doesn't ever advance in Star Wars (take a look at the Old Republic, set 25,000 years ago), it just changes.

That said, it's *far* too flawed to ever take an approach from an actual scientific perspective. There are accepted rules and limitations to technologies in Star Wars which, to be frank, don't exist and they 'obey' the laws of physics as they see fit. (Kind of it a bit like comic books.) Here's a good example - Lightsabers. What is a Lightsaber? Well, it used to be a laser sword which used Kyber crystals as a focusing lenses, now it is a 'plasma blade locked it a magnetic field' (which still uses Kyber crystals for ... something.) This isn't because the technology in Star Wars advanced - it's just because the technology on Earth did, so they had to give a better answer.

TL;DR - Science in Star Wars may as well be magic, as such it is subject to [Clarke's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws), and therefore the answer to your question is 'Whatever the plot requires so long as the reader doesn't lose their suspension of disbelief'.